# "Cushion" width on a column header?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a little loop function that resizes the columns based on the width of the text of the Column Header:

```
var columns = VView.gridViewCblID.Columns;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn clm in columns)
{
    VView.lblDummy.Text = clm.HeaderText;
    if (clm.Width > VView.lblDummy.Width && clm.Width <= 100)
    {
        clm.Width = VView.lblDummy.Width;
    }
}
```

However, due to a "cushion" that is automatically applied to the left of the Column HeaderText, the columns get a "bunched" appearance:

[image]

What is the actual width of that cushion, so I can apply it to the method? I.e.

```
clm.Width = VView.lblDummy.Width + (cushion *2);
```

Comment: What about `dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader` ?

Comment: @Loathing I'm doing this as part of a method that will resize the column depending on the current width after an `AutoResize`. I'm only wanting to resize certain columns.

Comment: You can set it on specific columns, see answer below.

Comment: @Loathing Sorry, I was unfortunately a bit vague. The idea is that after doing an `AutoResizeColumns`, some columns will be bigger, where as some need to be shrunk. However, I was hoping to write a generic method that could be used for all forms, regardless of what/how many columns they might have

Comment: You can still loop through all columns, get the current column width, set autosize to header, get the column width again, determine to set the new width, and then put the autosize mode back. If that has visual side effects, then you can create a clone with the same headers and fonts, and then dispose the clone after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use `AutoSizeColumnsMode` to do the work for you, and then set the resize mode back to manual. E.g.

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
dgv.Columns.Add("Cable Number", "Cable Number");
dgv.Columns.Add("Type", "Type");
dgv.Columns.Add("Length", "Length");

dgv.Columns["Type"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;

Form f = new Form();
f.Controls.Add(dgv);
dgv.HandleCreated += delegate {
    dgv.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate {
        var c = dgv.Columns["Type"];
        int w = c.Width;
        c.Width = w; // set current width, otherwise DGV reverts to previous 100 width
        c.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
    });
};
```