# DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader adjusts row header to 2 rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a column in a `DataGridView` like so:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn TaskOrderAmountColumn;

this.TaskOrderAmountColumn.DataPropertyName = "Amount";
this.TaskOrderAmountColumn.HeaderText = "Task Order Amount";
this.TaskOrderAmountColumn.Name = "TaskOrderAmountColumn";
this.TaskOrderAmountColumn.ReadOnly = true;
this.TaskOrderAmountColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

It displays like this:
[image]

The width of the column is too much. So I add this line:

```
this.TaskOrderAmountColumn.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
```

This does decrease the width of the column, but it has the side effect of causing the column header to go to 2 rows:

[image]

How do I decrease the width of the column and keep the row header at 1 row?

The [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203819/cushion-width-on-a-column-header?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) has the same effect. This is not surprising since the root cause of the problem appears to be that the width is not correctly calculated from the text "Task Order Amount". However, by changing one line:

```
c.Width = w + 25;
```

i.e., adding just a little to the calculated with, it displays the header row as a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have single line column headers when setting `AutoSizeMode` of the column to `ColumnHeader`, set [`ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadersheightsizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `DataGridView` to something different than `AutoSize`, for example set it to `DisableResizing` using designer or using code.

Also keep in mind that the `ColumnHeadersHeight` property should not be taller than a single line of text (Which is not taller by default, unless you change the height or column header font).